# How to dock a QDockWidgets inside a QSplitter?

Tags: qt, qtwidgets

I am trying to have a QSplitter accept QDockWidgets in my application. So far, I have done everything through the Qt Designer and what I have done is create three individual QWidgets. I then select all three of the QWidgets and I right click on them and select Layout->Lay out Vertically in a Splitter.

This lays all three of the widgets in a splitter quite nicely. I then drag a Dock Widget to the Object/Class Window in the top right and set them in the Splitters Widget. This places the QDockWidget happily inside the widget. However, when I fire up the program I cannot click and drag the dock widgets. If I double click the dock widget, the dock widget will pop out, however I cannot place it back since it was never technically docked. Which then creates the problem of the widget not being allowed to dock anywhere else. It cannot be docked on the QMainWindow class or in the QSplitter class.

Is there anyway to have a QDockWidget docked inside of a QSplitter and have the functionality of a QDockWidget?

Answer (score 0):

After you add the dock widget to the `QSplitter`, the widget has become part of the splitter.

You can try checking like this

```
//If sure of Dockwidget at zeroth position
QDockWidget *widget1 = (QDockWidget*)ui->splitter->children().at(0);
```

A Dockwidget has a feature of floating as a top level window.
But you can make a dockwidget look like other widgets by setting `QDockWidget::NoDockWidgetFeatures`

Either:

Go to the object window in Qtdesigner (top -> right)
And select the dock widget added to splitter.

In proeprties window, down below scroll down and look for "features".

Then uncheck the features like movalble, closable etc....
I made it NoDockWidgetFeatures.

or

You can set programmatically using `setFeatures(QDockWidget::NoDockWidgetFeatures)`

Comment: I am sorry, I think I wasn't clear in the question that I asked. What I actually want is to be able to move the dockWidgets to the other QSplitter positions. The problem I am having is that in that same properties window, `dockWidgetArea` and `docked` are greyed out. So I cannot dock the widget within the QSplitter.

Comment: Could you please try some thing like this. It actually do not insert, but shuffle the positions.... ui->splitter->insertWidget(1,((QWidget*)ui->splitter->children().at(0)));